# font awesome icons not showing up on ionic3 app

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have implemented font awesome icons in my ionic3 app, but it does not show up. My ionic project environment details,

```
cli packages: (C:\Users\acer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    Node : v8.4.0
    npm  : 5.8.0
    OS   : Windows 10

Misc:

    backend : pro
```

this is my intro.html file,

```
<ion-slides pager>
  <ion-slide style="background-color:yellow" >
      <i class="fas fa-utensils" style="font-size:120px;color:#ebebeb" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </ion-slide>

  </ion-slides>
```

this is in my index.html file

```
 <!-- font-awesome -->
  <link href="/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css" rek="stylesheet" type="text/html">
```

I have already added following code, as many blog posts and SO answers suggested in my copy.config.js file

```
copyFontawesomeFonts: {
    src: ['{{ROOT}}/node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/**/*'],
    dest: '{{WWW}}/assets/fonts'
  },
  copyFontawesomeCss: {
    src: ['{{ROOT}}/node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css'],
    dest: '{{WWW}}/assets/css'
  },
```

Comment: i checked it on the browser with ionic serve command

Comment: check it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47617601/font-awesome-installation-in-ionic-3-project

Comment: @Utpaul i did that too mate, i saw it... later i gave up with font awesome icons and added ionic icons

Comment: try `assets/css/font-awesome.min.css`. Remove the `/` in the url

Comment: To use font awesome in ionic already answered here, please go through    with this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42747846/font-awesome-with-ionic2/47055657#  )

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax error in linking stylesheet

```
<link href="/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css" rek="stylesheet" type="text/html">
```

It should be

```
<link href="/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Comment: Can you check the status code for this file in networks tab

Comment: If it is 404 then it is not loading stylesheet at all. You can also do one this use this link to check whether it is getting loaded http://localhost:3000/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css

Comment: Inspect the element in browser and see styles are getting updated for fa

Answer (score 1):

If you are linking a css-stylesheet  its type should always be

```
type="text/css"
```

Change it from

```
<!-- font-awesome -->
<link href="/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css" rek="stylesheet" type="text/html">
```

to

```
<!-- font-awesome -->
<link href="/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css" rek="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Comment: yeah bro, i gave up on font awesome icons and added ionic icons :( ... thanks for help  :) +1

Comment: if i'll get time then ill make a demo and ill post a proper way ... :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue earlier. Resolved it by loading css file from below url instead of loading from assets.

Comment: which url are you referring to?